# c# can you get position from axis without having a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm application that I would like to convert to a service. It has two mscharts on it. I don't need to see those charts anymore because the application creates bitmaps out of them. I am drawing a line on one chart depending on data from another chart, like this:

```
// Get Graphics object from chart
Graphics graph = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;

// Convert X and Y values to screen position
float pixelYMax = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default", AxisName.Y, CreatininePoint.YValues[0]);
float pixelXMax = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default", AxisName.X, CreatininePoint.XValue);
float pixelYMin = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default", AxisName.Y, CreatininePoint.YValues[0]-20);
float pixelXMin = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("Default", AxisName.X, CreatininePoint.XValue);

PointF point1 = PointF.Empty;
PointF point2 = PointF.Empty;

// Set Maximum and minimum points
point1.X = pixelXMax;
point1.Y = pixelYMax-10;
point2.X = pixelXMin;
point2.Y = 84;

// Convert relative coordinates to absolute coordinates.
point1 = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(point1);
point2 = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(point2);

float[] dashValues = { 4,2 };
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
blackPen.DashPattern = dashValues;
//e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(5, 5), new Point(405, 5));
//graph.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);

// Draw connection line
graph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), point2, point1);

// Create string to draw.
//String drawString = creatininept + " ng/mL";
String drawString = "67 ng/mL";

// Create font and brush.
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 7);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

// Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
PointF drawPoint = new PointF(point1.X,point1.Y+5);

// Draw string to screen.
graph.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);
```

is it possible to do this without having a form so that we can have a service running?

Comment: btw this is in the postpaint event

Comment: How does the form work? Users click a button and get a chart? How are you going to know, from a service, when to make a chart?

Comment: @mpell chart made from files in a folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bitmap canvas = new Bitmap(600, 480);
Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
```

.. then proceed with drawing on graph.